# Generate a permutation x number of times and calculate probability of it's Chi Square Distribution

Tags: java, apache, count, permutation, chi-squared

This question is extremely specific. I have found dozens of places telling you how to generate random permutations in Java, but it never got as far as calculating the probability of the Chi Square Distribution. Let me tell you that setting it up seemed fair enough, with many tutorials online, but one thing about this code that has really nagged me was the fact that in the second part of the assignment, I'm supposed to generate a random permutation of a string from index j where j is chosen randomly between the range of 0 and i. One method is supposed to output a probability of 1.0 all the time, which is biased and unfair, while the second method generates a probability of any number between 0 and 1.0. I've got the first part of that in part 1, but the second part I am having trouble making it not display 1.0 all the time. The assignment says that i simply steps through the array. In this circumstance, two styles of permutation generation were tried:

Method 1:

```
public static String generatePermutation(String prefix, String t){
    int n = 6;
    String s = "";
    StringBuilder test = new StringBuilder(t);
    if (n == 0){
        System.out.println(prefix);
    }
    else {
        for(int i = 0; i < n; i++){
            int j = randInt(0, i);
            char temp = test.charAt(j);
            test.setCharAt(j, test.charAt(i));
            test.setCharAt(i, temp);
        }
        s = test.toString();
        return s;
    }

    return s;
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Method 2:

```
public static String generatePermutation(String prefix, String t){
    char[] letters = t.toCharArray();
    shuffle(letters);
    String s = new String(letters);
    return s;
}

public static void shuffle(char[] array){
    int n = array.length;
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(n > 1){
        int k = rand.nextInt(n--);
        char temp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
    }
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

Both methods did not seem to give me a random number probability between 0 and 1.0. The current code for part 2 of the assignment is structured like this:

```
package math3323assignment7;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Map.Entry;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Collections;

import org.apache.commons.math3.distribution.ChiSquaredDistribution;

import com.google.common.collect.Multiset;
import com.google.common.collect.TreeMultiset;

public class assignment7part2 {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String s = "ABCDEF";
    Map<String, Integer> counts = new HashMap<>();
    Integer count;
    int expected = (int)factorial(s.length());
    for(int i = 0; i < 720000; i++){
        String t = generatePermutation("",s);
        count = counts.get(t);
        if(count == null){
            count = 1;
        }
        else {
            count = count + 1;
        }
        counts.put(t, count);
        System.out.println(t);
    }
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry : counts.entrySet()){
        System.out.println(entry.getValue() + " times: " + entry.getKey());
    }
    double chistat = 0.0;
    for(Entry<String, Integer> entry: counts.entrySet()){
        double di = entry.getValue() - expected;
        chistat += di*di/expected;
    }

    ChiSquaredDistribution chisq = new ChiSquaredDistribution(719.0);
    double prob = chisq.cumulativeProbability(chistat);

    System.out.printf("ChiSquare statistic = " + chistat + " the probability is " + prob);
}

public static String generatePermutation(String prefix, String t){
    char[] letters = t.toCharArray();
    shuffle(letters);
    String s = new String(letters);
    return s;
}

public static long factorial(int n){
    if (n <= 1){
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return n * factorial(n-1);
    }
}

public static void shuffle(char[] array){
    int n = array.length;
    Random rand = new Random();
    while(n > 1){
        int k = rand.nextInt(n--);
        char temp = array[n];
        array[n] = array[k];
        array[k] = temp;
    }
}

public static int randInt(int min, int max) {
    Random rand = new Random();
    int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;

    return randomNum;
}
```

}

As you can see, the Apache Math Distribution class from the Apache API is being used to create the Chi Square Distribution. A separate for loop is being used to calculate the Chi Square statistic. Unfortunately, when I run the program, the output always has a similar vein right at the very end to this:

```
 Prints all random permutations 720,000 times
 Counts all the times each permutation occurs, and print out the numbers
 ChiSquare statistic = 79360.74444444438 the probability is 1.0
```

I want the final part to print out like this:

```
 ChiSquare statistic = 79360.74444444438 the probability is 0.64
```

May you please help me fix this to where the final result of the second part of the program looks like the above line?

Answer (score 0):

The expected value you are using is incorrect. Your output should demonstrate a count that is somewhere around 1000 for each random permutation. One would expect each to be exactly 1000 in a non-random setting, because 720000 / 1000 = 720 which is what you are computing with
    int expected = (int)factorial(s.length());
Instead try
    int expected = 1000;